# searching on a List Of Case Class

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections, case-class

i need to search on a list of case class
example:in below example i want to know that `teamList` contains `name=php` or not.

```
scala> case class Team(name: String, image: String, nMember: BigInt, nYear: BigInt)
defined class Team

scala> val teamList=List(Team("scala","s.jpg",58,5),Team("java","cup.jpg",5400,18),Team("php","elephant.jpg",5800,8))
teamList: List[Team] = List(Team(scala,s.jpg,58,5), Team(java,cup.jpg,5400,18), Team(php,elephant.jpg,5800,8))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `filter` operation:

```
scala> case class Team(name: String, image: String, nMember: BigInt, nYear: BigInt)
defined class Team

scala> val teamList=List(Team("scala","s.jpg",58,5),Team("java","cup.jpg",5400,18),Team("php","elephant.jpg",5800,8))
teamList: List[Team] = List(Team(scala,s.jpg,58,5), Team(java,cup.jpg,5400,18), Team(php,elephant.jpg,5800,8))

scala> teamList.filter( _.name.contains("php") )
res0: List[Team] = List(Team(php,elephant.jpg,5800,8))
```

To merely check for existence of such an element:

```
scala> teamList.exists( _.name.contains("php") )
res5: Boolean = true
```

For more sophisticated matching, you can definitely go for `case-match` pattern matching.

```
scala> teamList.filter( _ match { case Team("php", _, _, _) => true case _ => false } )
res2: List[Team] = List(Team(php,elephant.jpg,5800,8))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> teamList.filter(t => t.name == "php")
res0: List[Team] = List(Team(php,elephant.jpg,5800,8))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use functional programming which enables a nice syntax for that kind of things :

```
val teamList=List(Team("scala","s.jpg",58,5),Team("java","cup.jpg",5400,18),Team("php","elephant.jpg",5800,8))
teamList.find(_.name == "php") // finds the first element verifying the predicate, if any
teamList.exists(_.name == "php") // returns true if such element exists, false otherwise
teamList.filter(_.name == "php") // finds all the elements verifying the predicate
```

Comment: can i get in boolean that it contains or not?

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti: You can use `exists` as described in my answer.

Comment: @tuxdna : that's right, I checked the doc too quickly and did not see it.

Comment: @Dici: I am glad to have helped :-)